# Installing TFS 2012 where some Visual Studio 2010 are still present?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Is it safe to install TFS 2012 where some Visual Studio 2010 dev machines are still present?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VS 2010 with TFS 2012, but you need to install SP1 and a GDR. See the [compatibility matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997788.aspx) for more information.

You won't be able to use the new features (like code review) nor create new team projects though.